# application crashes due to Fatal Exception in android?

Tags: android, exception

I am developing an  application in android in which i have 175 images, I have implemented   zoom in & zoom out on button click.

My functionality is working for 174 images but when implement it for 175 th image it crashes my application.

The log cat report is below:

```
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025): java.lang.VerifyError: different.pictures.Jaap$2
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at different.pictures.Jaap.onCreate(Jaap.java:1046)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-04 15:39:27.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please reformat your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Jaap` class you have several inner non-static classes. When you instantiate object of one of them, verifier tries to convert that inner class's methods to machine code. And it fails to do that.

To fix this you need to carefully examine logs prior to this exception. There should be some warnings about what was wrong with `different.pictures.Jaap$2` class.

Comment: @ inazaruk Thanks for the answer i tried to find out the error but did'nt understand much  07-04 16:27:10.578: INFO/ActivityManager(60): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=different.pictures/.Xyz }
07-04 16:27:10.619: DEBUG/PhoneWindow(7209): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e5cc10 has no id.
07-04 16:27:13.909: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7209): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2257 objects / 137024 bytes in 173ms
07-04 16:27:14.309: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44010868 different.pictures/.Xyz}